# Initialize single layer of a trained keras network and get predictions

Tags: python, keras, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I want to "damage" the layer of a trained keras network to see how the damage to this single layer affect network's performance.
So basically I want to :

1)load trained network

2)call the target layer and initialise its weights, put it back inside the network

3)calculate the network accuracy

I am using DenseNet201 model in Keras in Google Colab with TensorFlow backend

```
import tensorflow as tf
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from keras.applications.densenet import DenseNet201
from keras.preprocessing import image
from keras.applications.inception_v3 import preprocess_input,     decode_predictions
from keras.models import Model
from keras.callbacks import ReduceLROnPlateau, ModelCheckpoint
from keras.optimizers import Adam, SGD
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/gdrive')
from keras.models import load_model
model=load_model('/content/gdrive/My Drive/dense.h5')
adam = Adam(lr=0.001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=None, decay=0.0, amsgrad=True)
model.compile(optimizer=adam, loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
for layer in model.layers:
    print(layer.name)             
model.layers[conv1/conv].set_weights( keras.initializers.RandomNormal(mean=0.0, stddev=0.05, seed=None))
```

So, I am printing out the names of the layers, and than inputting exactly those names into set_weights, but each time I get this NameError

> NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call >last)
>  in ()
> ----> 1 model.layers[conv1/conv].set_weights( >keras.initializers.RandomNormal(mean=0.0, stddev=0.05, seed=None))
>
> NameError: name 'conv1' is not defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three issues that I see:

1. Use `model.get_layer(layer_name)` instead of `model.layers[layer_name]`.
2. Put quotes around `conv1/conv` like so `'conv1/conv'` to make it a string (name of the layer). You are getting the error because without quotes `conv1` and `conv` are considered variables (or any other python object), but you need a string here.
3. `layers.set_weights` [expects a list of numpy array](https://keras.io/layers/about-keras-layers/), but you pass it a `RandomNormal` object. You can use [`[np.random.normal(loc=0.0, scale=0.05, size=proper_shape)]`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.normal.html) instead (note the `[]`, it has to be a list), where you have to determine the proper shape of the layer's weight matrix via `proper_shape = model.get_layer('conv1/conv').get_weights()[0].shape` first.

Comment: model.layers['conv1/conv'].set_weights(keras.initializers.np.random.normal(loc=0.0, scale=0.05, shape=proper_shape))

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: Thanks a lot! However, still have an error, anything I'm doing wrong here?

model.get_layer('conv1/conv').set_weights(keras.initializers.np.random.normal(loc=0.0, scale=0.05, shape=proper_shape))

NameError: name 'proper_shape' is not defined

Comment: @Kirel Well, this is what I meant by "you have to determine the proper shape via ..." ;-) just replace `proper_shape` with `model.get_layer('conv1/conv').get_weights()[0].shape`.

Comment: @Kirel Oh, and also remove `keras.initializers.` from `keras.initializers.np.random.normal`. This is not meant to be offensive, but I would recommend to get some basic Python knowledge before you start working on more advanced stuff like this. Then very simple and basic issues like these will immediately make sense to you so that you can work much more efficiently as you don't have to ask here for these :)

Comment: I'm not offended in any case, in fact you are totally right

as I  understood the line should go as follows:

`model.get_layer('conv1/conv').set_weights(np.random.normal(loc=0.0, scale=0.05, shape=model.get_layer('conv1/conv').get_weights()[0].shape))`



however i get the following error:


`mtrand.pyx in mtrand.RandomState.normal()

TypeError: normal() got an unexpected keyword argument 'shape'`

Comment: Update: probably the correct parameter for numpy is size instead of shape, however this error now occurs:

ValueError: You called `set_weights(weights)` on layer "conv1/conv" with a  weight list of length 7, but the layer was expecting 1 weights. Provided weights: [[[[ 0.07777895  0.06511791 -0.01067184 ... -0.043...

Comment: @Kirel You are right :) the parameter name is `size`, not `shape`. I will update that. The new error probably comes from the missing `[]` around `np.random.normal(loc=0.0, scale=0.05, size=proper_shape)`. They are necessary because `set_weights` expects a list of weight matrixes. The `[]` will create a list containing one item.

Comment: Thank you very much, I still can't believe it, but it worked!!)

Comment: I realised that randomising the whole layer is indeed an overkill, I wonder if you might know how do I select a random subset of weights within a layer

Comment: @Kirel I'm not sure if I understand you correctly, but you can just get the current weights with `weights = get_weights()` and then override certain entries via `weights[0][x, y, z] = whatever_value_you_like` and then feed these weights back into the layer via `set_weights(weights)`.